# Converting elliptic orbits to circular ones

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, mathematics, celestial-mechanics

My physics teacher has told me that if we have an elliptic orbit under consideration, we can consider it equivalent to a circular orbit of radius equal to that of the semi-major axis of the ellipse.

Why can we do it? Is there an intuitive way to think about it? How can we prove it  mathematically?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2520778/

Comment: this might be of good reference

Comment: @AshwinBalaji Thanks for the link but I'm not sure it's the exact thing I'm looking for. We can probably prove it using the energy equations wrt the gravitational field but I'm not sure how... (I'm looking for a proof that uses more equations from physics by the way...)

Comment: Replace it for what purpose?

Comment: @G.Smith For simplicity in solving related questions(mostly competitive exams)

Comment: There are plenty of problems where an ellipse *can’t* be replaced by a circle. You had better gain more clarity on what your physics teacher meant.

Comment: @G.Smith I'm sure he meant that that an elliptical orbit is equivalent to a circular one with a radius equal to the semi-major axis of the ellipse. As far as the problems are concerned, I think I've not met any such questions( I've only finished my 12th grade as of now) I've almost always used this approach and it works out everytime I've used it

Comment: It very much depends on *exactly* what is meant by the word “equivalent”, which is a vague word with no definite meaning until the relevant equivalence is specified. Saying ellipses are equivalent to circles is analogous to saying that apples are equivalent to oranges; it’s meaningless unless you know *in what way* they are equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110882/discussion-between-sai-kartik-and-g-smith).

Comment: After our chat, it appears that what your teacher meant is that in Kepler’s Third Law the period depends only on the semimajor axis. That is different from “converting” an ellipse into a circle.

Comment: @G.Smith, "Equivalent" is a fine word. The only problem is, people forget that it doesn't mean anything until you say _for what purpose_ the things are equivalent.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That’s why I asked “Replace it *for what purpose*?”. It’ is indeed a fine word if you explain that, and a vague word if you don’t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what your professor is referring to is one of [Kepler's laws of planetary motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion), specifically Kepler's Second Law, which says that the area swept out by an orbiting body per unit time is the same. The immediate implication of this is that a body moves faster when it is closer to the body it is orbiting, and it will move slower when it is further away.

A side effect of this is that [you can show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Second_law) the area of an elliptical orbit with semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$ is:

$$ A = \pi a b $$

I'll leave it to you to put together the circular orbit details and to derive the equations for the second law.

Answer (score 3):

The concept which he didn't mention is that newton proved that all orbits following inverse square law and the time period is related semi major axis of ellipse. Now, if you put the minor axis length equal to major axis length, you turn an ellipse into a circle. After doing this, you can derive the time period by equating the inverse square force with centripetal force

reference:

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00033799100200181

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_two-body_problem